# Python PIL adds extra character when rendering text

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

When I use PIL to render text on an image, it adds an extra character when ® is in the text.

Example input: Brand Name®

Example output: Brand NameA®

It always seems to be the letter A.

Here's my code:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT, "fixtures/fonts/%s.otf" % font), int(font_size * 10), encoding="unic")
image = Image.new("RGBA", (width * 10, height * 10), convert_hex_color(background))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), text, convert_hex_color(foreground), font=font)
```

At this point I don't know why the extra character is in there. I'm using PIL 1.1.7

"text" is passed to the method. When printed to the console it appears like this:

```
About the REALTOR® Content Resource
```

Comment: Could you also include your definition or method of input for `text`?

Comment: Added text to the original post. It's just passed as a string that is coming from a django controlled database, therefore it should be unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Try converting `text` into a unicode object first.

When `text` is unicode:

```
import Image
import ImageFont
import ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf', 20)
image = Image.new("RGBA", (300,20), color = (0, 0, 0, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
text = u'About the REALTOR® Content Resource'
draw.text((0, 0), text, (255, 0, 0, 255), font=font)
image.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

yields

[image]

But when

```
text = 'About the REALTOR® Content Resource'
```

the code produces

[image]

---

If `text` is a `str`, to convert it to a `unicode` do

```
text = text.decode(encoding)
```

where `encoding` must be replaced with the actual [encoding of the string](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#standard-encodings). The correct encoding to use depends on how `text` was defined or generated.

Comment: Got to love coincidences: `u'®'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')` yields `u'Â®'`.

Comment: When I print text out of the database, it renders as follows:

    u'About the REALTOR\xae Content Resource'